# Name that JQuery: do you know the exact specific jquery plugin(s) used to create this widget?

Tags: jquery, widget

If you look at the following link: [What's new at New Hope](http://www.enewhope.org/index2.php)

Look at the widget on the page entitled "What's new at New Hope" which contains the Web2.0 equivalent of a MARQUEE (I guess that's what you'd call it) complete with fading images and "Read More" links.

**Question:** Can you identify the exact specific JQuery plugins used to generate this specific widget? The other stuff on the page is not relevant. I'm having a dog of a time discerning which plugins were used to create it and it alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them here and here:

- http://www.enewhope.org/assets/js/HomepageJSMinified.js
- http://www.enewhope.org/assets/css/homepagejs.css

Answer (score 2):

Why not just look at the code? http://www.enewhope.org/assets/js/turnstile.js

It appears to be mostly standard jQuery effects animate calls.

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate

Comment: I took a look but my eyes were starting to glaze over -- it must be time for a break. Thanks for the extra pair of eyeballs. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery Cycle Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) can do the image part, I don't know about the text stuff.